# Bathroom faucet set screw not Allen or Phillips

Tags: bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

This is a 2-handle bathroom faucet.  I need to remove the handles and replace the cartridges because the faucet is leaky.  My homeowners manuel says it is a Moen faucet.

When I remove the cap, I see a set screw, but it is not Allen or Philips (or standard).  So I have no way of removing the handle.  By the way, I did try simply pulling the handle off, but it did not come off after applying quite a bit of force.

[image: set screw]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Moen customer service. I've had good experience with them.

Comment: Looks like the screw may have been broken off. What does the other one look like?

Comment: The other one is precisely the same. :(  But yes I can contact Moen - thank you.

Comment: It does look like the screw head has broken off. If that's true, I'd expect you to be able to pull the handle off. Try "torquing" it at the end of the handle, there may well be some corrosion holding it in place, lifting up or pushing down on the handle may help break it loose. A bit of penetrating oil might also help, or you might be able to pry from below if there is a lip on the bottom of the handle. If you pry you probably want to use a block of wood or something similar to protect the marble.

Comment: They may both be broken...

Comment: Ok, maybe the original installer had broken them both.  That puts this out of my league.  I did try to pry a bit - but giving up now.  Time to call a plumber.  Thank you.